# Returning the inverse matrix from a cached object in R

Tags: r, matrix

Disclosure: This is from a programming assignment from a Coursera Course called R programming

The assignment is regarding lexical scoping and caching functions that may require a long computation time.  Specifically I am using `solve()` to find the inverse of a matrix and cache it using a free floating variable.  I am returning an error as described below.

First I stored a function in a variable `a<-makeCacheMatrix()`Then I run `a$set(matrix(1:4,2,2)`to store a matrix

When I run `cacheSolve(a)` I get `Error in as.vector(x, mode) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'`

From my understanding I suspect that I might be passing an atomic vector when it requires a matrix but I am not sure how to fix

My code:

```
makeCacheMatrix <- function(x = matrix()) {
  m<-NULL
  set<-function(y){
  x<<-y
  m<<-NULL
}
get<-function() x
setmatrix<-function(solve) m<<- solve
getmatrix<-function() m
list(set=set, get=get,
   setmatrix=setmatrix,
   getmatrix=getmatrix)
}

cacheSolve <- function(x=matrix(), ...) {
    m<-x$getmatrix()
    if(!is.null(m)){
      message("getting cached data")
      return(m)
    }
    matrix<-x$get
    m<-solve(matrix, ...)
    x$setmatrix(m)
    m
}
```

Comment: Look at your function definition for cacheMatrix. What is the object you are actually passing to that function. What creates that argument for cacheMatrix? Is it a matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Error in as.vector(x, mode) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'

Means that you try to coerce a function to a vector/matrix. Indeed in this line:

```
matrix <- x$get
m <- solve(matrix, ...)
```

`matrix` is a function , or `solve` need a matrix.

You just need to change this line :

```
matrix <- x$get
```

by

```
matrix <- x$get()
```